# Is it possible to integrate an existing Node.js version to NVM after installing it without NVM?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I have previously installed Node.js version 20.2.0 directly without utilizing nvm (Node Version Manager). However, I now desire to incorporate this existing Node.js installation into nvm without the need for reinstalling the same version using nvm. In other words, I want to include the already installed Node.js version into nvm.

i searched on the internet but i got nothing.

Comment: Possibly with some manual effort by checking out how nvm stores each Node.js version and then mimicking the same directory structure by copying the non-nvm-installed files. There isn't a built-in option for nvm to do this (although you can always use `nvm use system` to use the system-installed version).